# Is it possible to get all push-notifications outside the app?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I want to get all push-notificataions outside the app in Android. Is it possible to implement?

Comment: You want to get notification even if app is closed?

Comment: Yes, I want either implement even if app closed or if it's not. I need any ways to do it